# Using the Youtube API to find royalty-free and Creative-Commons music

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to create a software using the YouTube API to find Creative Commons videos and YouTube provided royalty free music in a custom created software?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible: in YouTube's search, you can filter by Creative Commons license. check out the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) and scroll down to the `videoLicense` section:

> `creativeCommon` – Only return videos that have a Creative Commons license

Answer (score 0):

You can use Freebase topics for find Creative Commons videos.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/searching_by_topic